# Dreamweaver CC Color Coding Is Not Working

Tags: dreamweaver

I just got Dreamweaver CC and the color coding is not working what-so-ever.  I've already done the following:

1. I tried to put checkmark by "Syntax Coloring"under the View menu, but it will not let me check it.  It's not grayed out; it just won't let me check it.
2. I downloaded a new Color xml file,and placed it in the Configurations folder.
3. I tried changing the colors around in a file in the Preference menu, but it won't apply the colors.
4. I deleted the Configurations folder so it will reset to default, but nothing.

You guys are my last resort.  If I can't get it to work I will have to re-install the entire program.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your best bet after going through all of those steps would be to, unfortunately, utilize your final option of re-installing Dreamweaver CC. Sorry if this isn't the answer you were expecting but that's what I would do at this point. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I re-installed the program, and it still didn't work, then I installed it on a different laptop and it's working perfect there. I'm not sure what the problem is, but what matters is that I'm still moving along.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out; and, I'm posting the solution to my own problem so readers won't endure as much suffering as I did trying to find the solution to this problem.  This little bitty tinny issue made my life miserable for several days.  Anyway, look below for the answer:

I had my HP Envy laptop running Win 8.1 color displayed set to high contrast.  Big mistake! I changed it back to display colors and my problem was solved.